# AngularJS / OAuth 2 transport-layer security

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth-2.0, http-post

The OAuth service I am trying to get the response from is working but something wrong in my code which does not make the request.

```
$http.post(myURL, 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + passWord,
    headers: { 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization Basic ' + btoa(secretWord) }).
        success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).
        error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: any error message in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error, therefore JS wont make the HTTP Post request, Try this:

```
$http.post(myURL, 'grant_type=password&username=' + userName + '&password=' + passWord,
    { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(secretWord) } }).
        success(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).
        error(function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
        });
```